# How to search query sets that have a specific value in a list in Django Rest framework

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework

## What I want to do

**Getting all query set which has a specific value in a list which is `ManyToManyField`.**

In short, if I type `http://localhost:8000/api/pickup/?choosingUser=5`, I would like to get all `PickUp_Places` that matches like `choosingUser = 5`. `choosingUser` comes from `ManyToManyField` so a `PickUp_Places` model has like `choosingUser = [2,3,5,7]`.

## Problem

I cannot search query sets by **a specific value in `list`.**
When I type `http://localhost:8000/api/pickup/?choosingUser=5`, I get all query sets that include ones don't have `choosingUser = 5`.

I am using `django_filters` in order to filter query sets. I read the documentation but I couldn't find how to get query sets by a value in a list.

If it is alright with you, would you please tell me how to do that?

Thank you very much.

=====         =========          ==========          =========

My code is like this.

models.py

```
class PickUp_Places(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    choosing_user = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="pick_up")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "pickup_places"
```

serializers.py

```
class PickUp_PlacesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PickUp_Places
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```
class PickUp_PlacesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PickUp_Places.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
    ]
    serializer_class = PickUp_PlacesSerializer

    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `choosingUser` from `url` override `get_queryset` method:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    choosingUser = self.request.query_params.get('choosingUser')
    queryset = choosingUser is not None and PickUp_Places.objects.filter(choosing_user__id=choosingUser) or PickUp_Places.objects.all()
    return queryset
```

Elaborated version:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    choosingUser = self.request.query_params.get('choosingUser')
    if choosingUser is not None:      
        queryset = PickUp_Places.objects.filter(choosing_user__id=choosingUser)
    else:
        queryset = PickUp_Places.objects.all()
    return queryset
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me that. Now it works well, I can get only `PickUp_Place` models that has a specific value. However, `http://localhost:8000/api/pickup` which is a url to get all `PickUp_Place` models is not working instead... Why is this happening?

Comment: @Toshi023Yuki That is because `choosingUser` is `None` in that url. Now, I have updated my answer plz review and let me know if you have any problem understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Everything works well. I realized what I want thanks to you. You are a lifesaver! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

One way to add filter based on M2M fields is to add `filter_fields` to your viewset, something like:

```
class PickUp_PlacesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PickUp_Places.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
    ]
    serializer_class = PickUp_PlacesSerializer

    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ('choosing_user', )
```

and then for filtering based on this field use `http://localhost:8000/api/pickup/?choosing_user=5` which will return all the places that have user with `id = 5` as it's choosing user.
If you want to filter based on multiple `choosing_user`s you can do:

```
class PickUp_PlacesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = PickUp_Places.objects.all()
        permission_classes = [
            permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
        ]
        serializer_class = PickUp_PlacesSerializer
    
        filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
        filter_fields = {
                'choosing_user__id': ['in',]
                }
```

and use `http://localhost:8000/api/pickup/?choosing_user=5,1,2` to filter multiple ids.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried what you taught me but it didn't work.